# Dll problem after moving project to other harddrive

Tags: c#, .net, dll, fluent-nhibernate, reference

I just changed harddisk and operating system from **XP to Win7**. 
Before my source code was on a **D:** drive, now they are on **F:**, under the same folder structure.

The problem is with a FluentNhibernate configuration. I get the following InvalidOperationException StackTrace:

```
   at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() in d:\Builds\FluentNH-v1.x-nh3\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs:line 115
   at TSI_Manager.FNH_Manager.CreateSessionFactory() in F:\.....
```

As you can see, it tries to access **D:**..  I don't know exactly what is trying to access what though. But looking in my project references, all references (except System...) are to **F:**, and set to **Copy Local = True**.

So what is still referring to **D:** ? And what steps have I missed to take?

cheers!

---

**EDIT:** 
Exception Details:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
  Source=TSI Manager
  StackTrace:
       at TSI_Manager.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 190
       at TSI_Manager.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_MainForm()
       at TSI_Manager.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm() in F:\My Jotta\VB\Projects VS2010\IB API Projects\9.64.16\ClientManager\v0004 Changing ActiveUser\TSI Manager\My Project\Application.Designer.vb:line 35
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at TSI_Manager.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException
       Message=An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
       Source=FluentNHibernate
       StackTrace:
            at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() in d:\Builds\FluentNH-v1.x-nh3\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs:line 115
            at TSI_Manager.FNH_Manager.CreateSessionFactory() in F:\My Jotta\VB\Projects VS2010\IB API Projects\9.64.16\ClientManager\v0004 Changing ActiveUser\TSI Manager\DAL\FnhManager.vb:line 43
            at TSI_Manager.FNH_Manager.ConfigureSessionFactory(String connectionStr) in F:\My Jotta\VB\Projects VS2010\IB API Projects\9.64.16\ClientManager\v0004 Changing ActiveUser\TSI Manager\DAL\FnhManager.vb:line 18
            at TSI_Manager.MainBL.InitializeDatabase() in F:\My Jotta\VB\Projects VS2010\IB API Projects\9.64.16\ClientManager\v0004 Changing ActiveUser\TSI Manager\Generic\MainBL.vb:line 174
            at TSI_Manager.MainBL..ctor() in F:\My Jotta\VB\Projects VS2010\IB API Projects\9.64.16\ClientManager\v0004 Changing ActiveUser\TSI Manager\Generic\MainBL.vb:line 92
            at TSI_Manager.MainForm..ctor() in F:\My Jotta\VB\Projects VS2010\IB API Projects\9.64.16\ClientManager\v0004 Changing ActiveUser\TSI Manager\GUI\Forms\MainForm.vb:line 6
       InnerException: NHibernate.HibernateException
            Message=Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver, NHibernate, Version=3.0.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4.
            Source=NHibernate
            StackTrace:
                 at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Connection\ConnectionProvider.cs:line 116
                 at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Connection\ConnectionProvider.cs:line 64
                 at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2 settings) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Connection\ConnectionProviderFactory.cs:line 50
                 at NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory.BuildSettings(IDictionary`2 properties) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\SettingsFactory.cs:line 83
                 at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSettings() in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 1687
                 at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 1239
                 at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() in d:\Builds\FluentNH-v1.x-nh3\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs:line 108
            InnerException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
                 Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
                 Source=mscorlib
                 StackTrace:
                      at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
                      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
                      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
                      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
                      at NHibernate.Bytecode.ActivatorObjectsFactory.CreateInstance(Type type) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Bytecode\ActivatorObjectsFactory.cs:line 9
                      at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Connection\ConnectionProvider.cs:line 107
                 InnerException: System.ArgumentException
                      Message=Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
                      Source=System.Data
                      StackTrace:
                           at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
                           at NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver..ctor(String providerInvariantName, String driverAssemblyName, String connectionTypeName, String commandTypeName) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Driver\ReflectionBasedDriver.cs:line 49
                           at NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver..ctor() in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Driver\SQLite20Driver.cs:line 28
                      InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not actually trying to access D: (as far as we can see) - it just thinks that's where the source for BuildSessionFactory is. You could rebuild FluentNHibernate yourself if you want to fix that, but I don't think it's the source of the problem.

Have a look at what the *message* of the exception is - that's likely to give rather more information.

Comment: I wish it told me more, however it only gives a standard message I get for almost all type of fluent config errors: Message is: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details. The error is: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

Comment: @bretddog: Well that's considerably more than you showed before. Next step is obviously to look at the InnerException and the PotentialReasons collection, as suggested. Did you do that?

Comment: ok, I must say I'm not very skilled at reading exception details. I posted the clipboard copy above. So if it gives you some hints I could learn maybe?  PotentialReasons says Count=0, not sure what that refers to?

Comment: @bretddog: Well this looks like the relevant bit: "Message=Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver" - it sounds like you're missing an assembly.

Comment: Right, it must be I forgot to install SQLIte, will do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key issue is the InnerException with the message:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

It looks you need to install the relevant data provider to the GAC on your new machine or make sure sure it correctly referenced within your project.

It appears that the latest version of the SQLite provider can be obtained from:

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Comment: Cheers, seems so. What would be the correct install options to chose here: http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/9645/screenshot2011051402411.png  ?